# How to make a matrix that had diffrentation without functions

Tags: matrix, webmathematica

I want to make a matrix in Mathematica that looks like this:

[image]

Any idea on how I can do this?

Comment: _"looks like this"_  If you want those characters to be displayed, maybe you can use `DisplayForm@
 MatrixForm@{{FractionBox["\[PartialD]", "\[PartialD]x"], 0}, {0, 
    FractionBox["\[PartialD]", "\[PartialD]y"]}, {FractionBox[
     "\[PartialD]", "\[PartialD]y"], 
    FractionBox["\[PartialD]", "\[PartialD]x"]}}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possiblity is to define the function d as:

```
d = {{D[#, x], 0}, {0, D[#, y]}, {D[#, x], D[#, y]}} &
```

To apply this operator to a particular function:

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + Sin[y]
```

Then:

```
d[f[x, y]]

{{2 x, 0}, {0, Cos[y]}, {2 x, Cos[y]}}
```